# Resize images in django-tinymce

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I have a tinymce form in my Django app, this is the configuration:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'branding': False,
    'height': '300px',
    'width': '100%',
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'plugins': 'link image table',
    'toolbar': 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image table',
    'toolbar_mode': 'floating',
    'relative_urls': False,
    'remove_script_host': False,
    'convert_urls': True,
    'images_max_dimensions': (800, 800),
}
```

But `'images_max_dimensions': (800, 800),` doesn't work and images go beyond the borders they're supposed to.

I tried to resize the images by rendering the view with pillow but it's taking too much resources.